# Is Process Mining used just to infer business process models?

Tags: data-mining, event-log, business-process

I have been searching about mining event logs (Process Mining). I wonder if there are other uses besides infering the process model (eg. improving the process). Until now I haven't found any other practical application. Can someone recommend me authors, publications about it (if there is other application), or recommend any keywords that I can search for to find it. Thank you!

Comment: [I am afraid you are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). While this is an interesting discussion topic, stackoverflow is a place for solving concrete programming-related problems. Is there are particular problem you are stuck with ?

Comment: @khalito I have found questions similar to mine (on stack overflow) that were answered before. Business process executions may generate data (that may become Big Data), and Data Mining techniques can be used to extract knowledge from this data. I just didn't find someone who actually made it, because I didn't find the correct way of searching for it. So I hope maybe one day someone will read this post and will be able to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this twitter thread: https://twitter.com/JorgeMunozGama/status/1236967153825275904

Many interesting applications from soccer analyzing to wind turbines monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a look at this wonderful book: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662498507

It gives a detailed understanding of process mining and its applications.

Answer (score 0):

Three alternative uses of process mining other than creating business models are:

1. Discovering patient pathways (a patient moving between different healthcare providers or different departments in a hospital). This information may also be relevant for parties that are not healthcare providers themselves, for example the insurer. This can also help with fraud detection. For example, if the process map shows that procedure X (for example an x-ray) is usually followed by procedure Y (for example a knee operation), and the insurer finds that in certain cases procedure Y is done but X is missing, that may be indicative of a type of fraud. In this example, process mining can easily identify all the cases that had an x-ray but never showed op for a knee operation.
2. Discovering networks (who refers work to who and at what intensity). In this case you do not use the product for the 'activity' column in the event log, but instead label the name of the provider as the 'activity' column in the event log. This is also known as a 'work hand over' map. It is slightly different than a regular process map because it does not visualize activities anymore, but instead visualizes the flow between key players.
3. Process mining allows for exact quantifications of throughput times and bottlenecks, which regular BPMN models can not do.

Answer (score 0):

Process mining can be used to obtain process models, even if there are no event logs to be mined.

See the [BPMN Sketch Miner](https://www.bpmn-sketch-miner.ai) for how to do so.